# Solr Indexing Design Requirement

Tags: solr

I am having a 5 tables in database namely State,District,City,Locality and Pincode(Hierarchy as mention).
  Each table is having the Foreign Keys corresponding to all parents in hierarchy.But some of the Pincodes maynot have the locality id.I am trying to indexing this data with Solr.
So far i am indexing such as below

```
    <doc>
    <str name="state">Punjab</str>
    <arr name="district">
       <str>test</str>
       <str>test1</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="city">
      <str>abc</str>
      <str>dfsdf</str>
     </arr>
    <arr name="locality">
      <str>fggf</str>
      <str>gddd</str>
     </arr>
     <arr name="pincode">
      <str>123</str>
      <str>345</str>
     </arr>
</doc>
```

But i hope this is not the correct way for fetching the data as there is no relation between district and city,city and locality etc..
help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at this problem backwards. You need to work from the results. What do you want to **find**?

Imagine you already have everythin working correctly. Given that, what individual record would be in that search result (pincode-level entries?). Then, de-normalize down to that level and include all the information required to find that record.

See [the presentation from Gilt](http://www.slideshare.net/trenaman/personalized-search-on-the-largest-flash-sale-site-in-america) regarding how they refactored their initial architecture to reflect their needs better. Ignore all the technical details for now, just follow the logic arguments.

Then, you will probably have a (separate) technical question on how to implement it.